# no Wifi Adapter found , earlier everything was working, not working suddenly wireless lan hard-blocked

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, rfkill, lshw

I am using Dell Inspiron 15, 3537 ( approx 7 yrs old )

I am having Ubuntu 20 lts. Every thing was fine.

My laptop hanged while uploading some large files, in bulky resource eating CHROME.

I tried every thing to stop the process.

But in vain.. No method known to human worked.

It was just froozen.

Now , with anger, I hit the Power button. Even that hanged.

After holding the power button for some time, finally it shut down.

After booting, every thing was quite the same. Except

[image]

my wifi , which was earlier working, had now stopped working.

You are reading me because I had a wire which you call ethernet cable

But now, leave every thing else, and please help me..

I am in deep agony..

Look at the results of some terminal commands

```
❯ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for aahnik: 
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: 74:86:7a:37:59:7b
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0600000-b0600fff memory:b0400000-b0403fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 0c:84:dc:01:29:93
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.4.0-48-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:b0500000-b057ffff memory:b0580000-b058ffff
```

hmm

```
❯ tail -f /var/log/messages
tail: cannot open '/var/log/messages' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: no files remaining
```

---

```
> iwconfig
lo      no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          
enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
```

HELP !!

Dont worry about my date, its safely backed up.

Give me a solution other than re installing ubuntu

Comment: can you edit thequestion with the output of this commands? `ifconfig` `iwconfig` ?

Comment: hmm. done. plz help @johncli

Answer (score 1):

hula lall la a

I am overflowing with joy..

BECOS I FOUND THE SOLUTION

in my question I said, I forced shutdown.

i earlier tried `ctrl + alt + f1` to restart the display manager.

[image]

I read somewhere about this `ctrl + alt + f1`, but don't remember

While pressing and throwing my impulse on the keys, I accidentally had pressed
`fn + f2` which unfortunately was the physical switch for hard blocking the wifi adapter.

So my wireless plan got hard blocked.

I read this

[image]

and then saw this

[image: IMG_20201013_111226]

Then I pressed `Fn + F2`. And heavens showered flowers upon me ...

**rfkill kills your misery**

so earlier

```
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

and now

```
0: dell-rbtn: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

do you know what is different bw my question and answer ?

I had asked the question with my ethernet, and answering it with my wifi

Comment:  what a wake up read!! 